# How to replace any string, of a column, in a data frame to a empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this function which drops a row in my DF, if any string is contained inside a cell within a column called 'Aborted Reason'.

Now the only thing is, I need to change some of the logic. This column now contains a load of free text that changes for every row. Is there away that I can replace ANY string in the cell to a empty string aka `''`.

Without dropping the whole row.

```
def drop_aborted_reason():
    for i in df.index:
        if type(df.loc[i, 'Aborted Reason']) == str:
            df.drop(i, inplace=True)
```

This is the code I have right now, and its dropping the whole row. I tried doing a `df.replace` instead of `df.drop` but I'm not getting the result I need. Also I cant drop the column, as this column's is required for a schema that is ingested by a third party.

Can anyone offer some guidance on this?

An example of the data I have got in the column

| Aborted Reason | Job status |
| --- | --- |
| Job was aborted due to cats | Aborted |
|  | Completed |
| This reasons could be anything | Aborted |
| i dont know why this was aborted | Aborted |
| Show me the meaning of salsa | Aborted |
| cleo the leo | Aborted |

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `df.loc[i, 'Aborted Reason'] = ''` instead of the `df.drop(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Aborted Reason':[9,'Aborted text',8,'Another text',7, 'What happened?',
                      6,'Take a break',99,'Job was aborted due to cats'],
    'Job status':['Completed', 'Aborted', 'Completed', 'Aborted', 'Completed', 'Aborted',
                  'Completed', 'Aborted', 'Completed', 'Aborted']})

def drop_aborted_reason():
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if type(df.iloc[i]['Aborted Reason']) == str:
            df.iloc[i]['Aborted Reason'] = ''

print('Initial Dataframe:\n',df)
drop_aborted_reason()
print('\nEmpty strings Dataframe:\n',df)
```

And the output:

```
Initial Dataframe:
                 Aborted Reason Job status
0                            9  Completed
1                 Aborted text    Aborted
2                            8  Completed
3                 Another text    Aborted
4                            7  Completed
5               What happened?    Aborted
6                            6  Completed
7                 Take a break    Aborted
8                           99  Completed
9  Job was aborted due to cats    Aborted

Empty strings Dataframe:
   Aborted Reason Job status
0              9  Completed
1                   Aborted
2              8  Completed
3                   Aborted
4              7  Completed
5                   Aborted
6              6  Completed
7                   Aborted
8             99  Completed
9                   Aborted
```

I created a Dataframe to have something to work on, but this solution works for any string in the column `'Aborted Reason'`. Here is another take with your updated column:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Aborted Reason':['Job was aborted due to cats', '',
                          'This reasons could be anything',
                          'i dont know why this was aborted',
                          'Show me the meaning of salsa', 'cleo the leo'],
        'Job status':['Aborted', 'Completed', 'Aborted', 'Aborted', 'Aborted', 'Aborted']})

def drop_aborted_reason():
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if type(df.iloc[i]['Aborted Reason']) == str:
            df.iloc[i]['Aborted Reason'] = ''

print('Initial Dataframe:\n',df)
drop_aborted_reason()
print('\nEmpty strings Dataframe:\n',df)
```

And the output:

```
Initial Dataframe:
                      Aborted Reason Job status
0       Job was aborted due to cats    Aborted
1                                    Completed
2    This reasons could be anything    Aborted
3  i dont know why this was aborted    Aborted
4      Show me the meaning of salsa    Aborted
5                      cleo the leo    Aborted

Empty strings Dataframe:
   Aborted Reason Job status
0                   Aborted
1                 Completed
2                   Aborted
3                   Aborted
4                   Aborted
5                   Aborted
```